# How can we show a set S and a subset of S have the same cardinality? Specifically: (below)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have a set $A$ with cardinality $c$ (continuum) and I take a subset of $A$, call it $A_1$, I want to show that $A_1$ also can have cardinality $c$. 
(Not sure if this helps or makes things easier, in the problem, we actually take 2 disjoint subsets of $A$, $A_1$ and $A_2$ and need to show they both also have cardinality $c$. But I thought if we can show it for one subset, then it can follow for the other subset. )
What I have tried doing was taking some subset $A_1$ of $A$ and selecting $A_2 = A - A_1$ so that they're disjoint. And clearly $|A_1| \leq A$, similarly for $|A_2|$ and I wanted to show $|A| \leq |A_1|$ to show they have the same size (for $A_2$ also) but am not sure how I would go about defining a 1 to 1 function

Comment: Please give the specific problem. As such this makes little sense to me.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What you're trying to show (that both subsets have the same cardinality as $A$), without any further supposition, is not true, so you won't be able to show it. If $A$ is $\left[0,1\right] $, then two disjoint subsets of $A $ could be $A_1= \{ 0 \}$, $A_2=\{1\}$. Even if you additionally assume that $A = A_1 \cup A_2$, it still is not the case that both necessarily have the same cardinality as $A $, considering $A_1=\left[0,1\right) $, $A_2=\{1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify what that subset is, it will be impossible to define such an injection, because it is certainly not true that any subset of $S$ has the same cardinality of $S$.

But if your question is: Is it possible for *some* subset of $S$ to have the same cardinality of $S$? Then the answer is trivial: of course: $S$ itself!

Finally, if your question is: Is it possible for a strict subset of $S$ to have the same cardinality as $S$?  The the answer is: Sure, as long as $S$ is infinite. For in that case we can take out any 1 element $x$ from $S$, and $S \setminus\{x\}$ will have the same cardinality as $S$